# FB Messenger checkbox plugin is in hidden status in Test App

Tags: plugins

FB Messenger checkbox plugin is in hidden status in Test App which was not live. Please let me know if the checkbox plugin will only render for live Apps?

Tried with different App Ids and Page Ids but still FB checkbox plugin is not getting rendered